# How are these types differentiated?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I read [here @ java.sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html) that *`int[] iarr`* is a primitive array and *`int[][] arr2`* is a object array. What is the difference between a primitive type and an object type ? How are the above two different from each other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int[]` is a primitive array because it contains elements of primitive type `int`. Every array itself is Object, so array of primitives is object too.

`int[][]` is a array of `int[]`, i.e. each element of `int[][]` contains array of integers. But since array is a object `int[][]` contains objects, not integers.

Answer (score 3):

From the link you've provided:

> Primitive arrays contain elements that are of primitive types such as int and boolean.
>   Object arrays contain elements that are of reference types such as class instances 
>   and other arrays

In the first case, each array element is an `int`, which is a primitive type, resulting in a *primitive array*. In the second case, each element of the array is `int[]`, which is an array and therefore an object (an array itself is an object).